# I want to create my notification if the alert date is equal to now date and notification will create all dates from alert to vaccine date

Tags: java, android, date, android-notifications

*Here is the code I want to create notification from alert date to vaccination date this notification will create all dates from alert to vaccine how I can do this?*

```
                SimpleDateFormat da = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM,yyyy");
                try {
                    Date al = da.parse(alert);
                    Date out = da.parse(output);
                    Date vac=da.parse(date);
.................................................................................................
                    if (out.before(al)&& Status.equals("Pending")&& vac.after(out)) {
                        Cursor ca= db.child_show_data(idofchild);
                        if(ca.moveToFirst())
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                nameofchild= ca.getString(ca.getColumnIndex("name"));
                            }while(ca.moveToNext());
                        }
                        Intent notificationintent=new Intent(MybackgroundService.this,done_Activity_of_status.class);
                        notificationintent.putExtra("id",id);
                        notificationintent.putExtra("name",name);
                        notificationintent.putExtra("status",Status);
                        notificationintent.putExtra("date",date);
                        notificationintent.putExtra("idofchild",idofchild);
                        notificationintent.putExtra("id_vacinedetail",id_detail);
                        notificationintent.putExtra("numdays",numdays);

                        notificationintent.setAction("Actionstring"+System.currentTimeMillis());

            '''''''''''''''''''            PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivities(MybackgroundService.this,
                                0,
                                new Intent[]{notificationintent},
                                0);
                        Intent snooze=new Intent(MybackgroundService.this,Timer_Tosnooze.class);
                        snooze.putExtra("id",id);
                        snooze.putExtra("name",name);
                        snooze.putExtra("status",Status);
                        snooze.putExtra("date",date);
                        snooze.putExtra("idofchild",idofchild);
                        snooze.putExtra("alert",alert);
                        snooze.putExtra("id_vacinedetail",id_detail);
                        snooze.putExtra("numdays",numdays);
                        snooze.setAction("Actionstring"+System.currentTimeMillis());
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent1=PendingIntent.getActivities(MybackgroundService.this,0, new Intent[]{snooze},0);


                        NotificationCompat.Builder notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

                                .setContentText(nameofchild+"  "+name+"  "+date+"   "+Status)
                                .setContentTitle("Vacination")
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_sys)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_noti,"Done",pendingIntent)
                                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_noti,"remind me",pendingIntent1)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
                        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
                        NotificationManager manager=(NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        manager.notify(Unique_Integer_Number,notification.build());
                        Unique_Integer_Number++;


                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        } while (c.moveToNext());
```

...........................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

this is the True way to solve this 
 if (al.before(out)&& Status.equals("Pending")&& vac.after(out)) {